# set progress dialog over main layout

Tags: android, android-webview, progressdialog

I have a code in which the progress dialog appears along with main layout. I want the progress dialog to be on the forefront and the main layout in background just like its showing the link [enter link description here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-transparent-progress-dialog-on-android/).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText urlEditText;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
                if (validateUrl(url)) {
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(url);

                }
            }

            private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {   
         @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

         @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(100);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

         @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
             progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int progress) {
        this.progress.setProgress(progress);        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post xml code ?

Comment: hre is the link http://imgur.com/6FvgMss

Comment: Try to put webview below reference to urlContainer instead of progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WebChromeClient instead of WebViewClient to show and update progress :

show pregress bar before call webview.loadUrl() :

```
if (validateUrl(url)) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Update progress in onProgressChanged :

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            progress.setProgress(newProgress);
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but where should I insert the webView.setWebChromeClient code? As I already have WebviewClient.